# Show Block view of Restricted Content Type

Tags: views, blocks, nodes, users

I have a content type of Events which i make restricted for anonymous users via content_access module. But on the home page there is a block view of most recent Events. I don't want that block view to be hidden from anonymous users. I have selected all roles in the view settings so that i should show but i think because of contect_access restrictions on Event Content Type its not displyaing the block.

How can i show that block ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Views UI there is a setting under 'Advanced' called 'Query Settings'. Click on 'Settings' next to it, then in the next popup make sure to select 'Disable SQL rewriting'.

> Disabling SQL rewriting will disable node_access checks as well as
>   other modules that implement hook_query_alter().